# Spring Zuul - Random "Forwarding errors" when use HTTPS

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

We have a set of micro-services deployed on single server which work hidden behind Apache.

Before spreading them out among different servers we wanted to make communication secure so HTTPS was turned on.

After that problems on **spring zuul** occurred. Randomly some requests fail because **spring zuul** is not able to forward them to specific **micro-service** (even if service is on the same server). We are getting following exception:

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:188)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:163)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:111)
        at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112)
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193)
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157)
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118)
        at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96)
        at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116)
        at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:157)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:44)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter.doFilter(TraceFilter.java:186)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:486)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: service-foo timed-out and no fallback available.
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$22.call(AbstractCommand.java:819)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$22.call(AbstractCommand.java:804)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:140)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$DeprecatedOnFallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1472)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$FallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1397)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87)
        at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onError(Subscribers.java:230)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeThrow.call(OnSubscribeThrow.java:44)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeThrow.call(OnSubscribeThrow.java:28)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:142)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$1$1.run(AbstractCommand.java:1154)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:45)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:41)
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.hystrix.SleuthHystrixConcurrencyStrategy$HystrixTraceCallable.call(SleuthHystrixConcurrencyStrategy.java:188)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable.run(HystrixContextRunnable.java:61)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$1.tick(AbstractCommand.java:1159)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.util.HystrixTimer$1.run(HystrixTimer.java:99)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.handleTimeoutViaFallback(AbstractCommand.java:997)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.access$500(AbstractCommand.java:60)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$12.call(AbstractCommand.java:610)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$12.call(AbstractCommand.java:601)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:140)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
```

What is weird as almost all requests pass - only some of them fail.

> Have tried already a few solutions but did not help:
>
> - use lower version (4.4.1) of httpclient
> - use lower version (Dalston.SR2) of spring cloud
> - increase the number of MaxRequestWorkers on Apache
> - Make time for connection longer (even if failing zuul requests took less then 3 seconds):
>
>   - ribbon.ConnectTimeout = 3000
>   - ribbon.ReadTimeout = 20000
>
> So more in the same time I turn on "testing scripts" like:
>
> - ping my server all the time
> - send requests via HTTPS to foo-service avoiding ZUUL
>
> Both operations were made in parallel with sending requests via ZUUL.
>   The ping and direct calls to foo-service have been working even in
>   "time moments" when Spring Zuul was failing.

**When we switch back to HTTP it works again**. The only difference which I see is that in case of HTTPS whole traffic is going through Apache.

The last thing which I see in logs before exception is:

```
2017-11-03 12:10:45.718 DEBUG [zuul,9aceeded808781ba,9aceeded808781ba,false] 873 --- [io-8009-exec-49] h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection : http-outgoing-10859: Close connection
2017-11-03 12:10:45.718 DEBUG [zuul,9aceeded808781ba,9aceeded808781ba,false] 873 --- [io-8009-exec-49] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Connection discarded
2017-11-03 12:10:45.718 DEBUG [zuul,9aceeded808781ba,9aceeded808781ba,false] 873 --- [io-8009-exec-49] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection released: [id: 10859][route: {s}->https://my.server.com:443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 4 of 50; total allocated: 5 of 200]
2017-11-03 12:10:45.724  WARN [zuul,9aceeded808781ba,9aceeded808781ba,false] 873 --- [io-8009-exec-49] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering
```

But have no any idea what more could I check to find the source of the problem.

Any ideas?
Do we miss some configuration changes which should be done?

Comment: Https is a bit slower. You probably need to increase the Hystrix timeout

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue you're describing. Underlying issue is that HTTPS protocol is slower (especially first time when validating connection between client and server). By default Ribbon has a 2000ms timeout for Hystrix and the configurations you usually do to override this for all hystrix commands don't seem to apply to Ribbon.

This is due to some code within the method getSetter in AbstractRibbonCommand:93. If you check that line you'll see the properties of circuit breaker are using the default defined in a static class within Ribbon code.

When the CircuitBreaker object for the connection for your service is started it'll use this definition if no other is found - class HystrixCircuitBreaker:169. I haven't explored much into why the default Hystrix configurations aren't picked up here.

I'm still trying to figure out myself the best solution for this but the following property on the zuul service solved this:

```
hystrix.command.RibbonCommand.<my-service-name>.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=5000
```

Ideally I'd prefer this to use the default hystrix timeout period so I'll most likely be adding a Configuration class to instantiate the RibbonCommand for all my services based on the configured Zuul Routes. I'll update this answer if I do that so it can be used for future reference.

The classes I'm refering to are part of Hystrix Core 1.5.12, which is a part of Spring Cloud Edgware release.